# Not able to create object using call method to the function. How can I create an object using call method?

Tags: javascript

Here I have created a constructor function. I want to create an object using call method to this function. I have used the empty object as the current object and passed an argument.

```js
function Circle(radius){
    this.radius = radius;
    this.draw = function(){
        console.log('draw');
    }
}



let cirlce1 = Circle.call({}, 1);

console.log(cirlce1);
```

I am getting undefined in the console. I want to know where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the current object in the Circle function. Here you are creating a variable equals to what Circle returns. Because it's not returning anything, you get undefined. So you only have to add a return statement at the end returning this. Which in this case is the empty object you passed originally in call.

```
function Circle(radius){
    this.radius = radius;
    this.draw = function(){
        console.log('draw');
    }
    return this;
}

let circle = Circle.call({}, 1);
console.log(circle);
```

After that, your empty object now has the radius property and the draw method. Then you return it. The result is saved in the circle variable.

Comment: Yep the `new` operator does everything. I was just exploring the call method and left the return statement. Thank you for clarifying